# Bartlett's test of sphericity

Tags: r

I am trying to run a Bartlett's sphericity test in R with my data frame which looks like this:
[image]

```r
library(REdaS)
bart_spher(data)
```

> Error in bart_spher(data) :
> "x" contains missing values and use = "everything"
> Check your data and set the "use" argument appropriately.

Can you please help me?

I have chosen argument in "use" to deal with NA
I change my data frame to matrix and
and did it numeric it always give this sort of error

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one of the alternative "use" options. "pairwise.complete.obs" is the most lenient, but may cause some statistical issues: the "Treatment of Missing Values" section in `?bart_spher` (i.e. the [help page for the function](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/REdaS/html/bart_spher.html)) explains in a little more detail.

Here's an example:

```r
x <- matrix(1:12,4,3)
x[2,2] <- NA
bart_spher(x)
```

> Error in bart_spher(x) :
> "x" contains missing values and use = "everything"
> Check your data and set the "use" argument appropriately.

```r
bart_spher(x, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

```
    Bartlett's Test of Sphericity

Call: bart_spher(x = x, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

     X2 = Inf
     df = 3
p-value < 2.22e-16

Warning: Used n = 3.67.
```